# mgo $inc update not working

Tags: go, mgo

Am trying to update the view count each time a particular blog is visited

```
type Blog struct {
    ID          bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Topic       string
    TimeCreated string
    Views       int
    Sections    []Section
}
type Section struct {
    Name    string
    Content string
}
```

and contoller

```
func Blogs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id := r.FormValue("id")
    if id != "" {
        blog := model.Blog{}
        colQuerier := bson.M{"_id": bson.ObjectIdHex(id)}

        e := mCollection.Find(colQuerier).One(&blog)
        if e != nil {
            console.PrintError(e)
            return
        }
        views := blog.Views
        fmt.Println(views)
        change := bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{"Views": 1}}

        e = mCollection.Update(colQuerier, change)
        if e != nil {
            console.PrintError(e)
        }

        jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(blog)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, string(jsonData))
     }
}
```

//console is an internal package

the code fetches the content but doesn't increment the Views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, 
so even though the model had 'Views'. In the collection it was 'views' so it kept incrementing the 'Views', which never showed up because golang was looking for 'views'.

so the working code is

`change := bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{"views": 1}}`

Comment: got a unrecognized pipeline stage name $inc... Which driver mongo were you using ?